# Where are all the ElasticSearch Config Params listed?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm messing around with a lot of the elastic search configuration parameters in the elasticsearch.yml file.  I keep finding gems of knowledge on blog pages enumerating new configuration parameters.  Is there a list someplace that enumerates all of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might try this.  (right sidebar) 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules.html

Comment: Not quite.  I'm looking for a a list of things like: indicies.fielddata.cache.type [soft/..], index.search.slowlog.*, etc.  They're all around the website for elasticsearch, just not in one place, as far as I can tell.

Comment: yeah... there are a handful of settings that they don't list.  which should be better documented on 1.0 release   https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/config/elasticsearch.yml